# two dimensional array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I try to make a function that gets a string delivered like "Hello".
The function's return value should be an array of strings that would look like

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
```

I really don't know how to do that. My current code is super messy because I made a lot of adjustions and everyone made it worse.

```
char stutterString(char string[])
{
  rowLength = strlen(string);
  char help_string[][rowLength]; // I wanted to make the onedimensiol string i get into a two dimensial one so I can then compare my strings in a forloop 

    strcpy(help_strig, string); // I'm not sure if that's how you copy a 1d string into a 2d string, I guess not.
```

My loops look like

```
for(; count1 <= COLUMN; count1++)
  {
    for(count2 = 0; count2 <= NumberRow; count2++)
    {
      new_string[count1][ROW] = help_string[0][count2];

      ROW++
    }
    NumberRow++;
  }

// NumberRow indicates the limit on the letters that should be copied. like in the beginning it's 1 for H, then 2 for the He and so on..
//count1 is for the column number we r currently and count2 for the row
```

Any ideas how I could achieve that easier / where to improve my code?

Comment: `char help_string[][rowLength];` is illegal, as is `strcpy(help_strig, string);`. Also it's not possible to return an array of strings in C. I'd suggest reading some tutorials or books about arrays, before continuing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes, I'll still have to read A LOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a two dimensional array, e.g.

```
char array[50][200];
```

Then to copy a 1D string into the array you would do this

```
strcpy( array[0], "Hello" );
```

To copy a portion of a string from a 2D array to another 2D array, use the `strncpy` function, e.g.

```
length = 3;
strncpy( new_string[index], help_string[10], length );
new_string[index][length] = '\0';
```

That would copy the first 3 characters of `help_string[10]` into the `new_string` array. Note that `strncpy` may not terminate the string with a NUL character (depending on the length of the source string) so that needs to be done after the copy.

Comment: Be wary of `strncpy()`; it does not always null-terminate the string it copies to.  If the array is already zeroed, it won't matter.  If it was used for something else before hand, it does matter.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. Using dynamic allocation can reduce the program's memory footprint at runtime as well as file size of the executable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **
stutterString(char *str)
{
  int i, sz, len=strlen(str);
  char **rtn; /* a 2-dimensional array */
  char *s;

  /* allocate the number of rows plus an extra one to indicate the end of list.
     calloc() will set all "rows" to NULL.
  */
  rtn = (char **)calloc(len+1, sizeof(char **));
  for(i=0; i<len; ++i) {
    /* allocate the string -
      '2' is 0 offset plus i plus 1 for \0
    */
    s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (i+2));
    memcpy(s, str, i+1);
    s[i+1] = '\0';
    rtn[i] = s;
  }

  return(rtn);
}

int
main()
{
  int i;
  char **stutter;   /* think of it as a 2-dimensional array */

  stutter = stutterString("hello");

  /* Print and free the string. It's important to free when
     you are done with the memory! */
  for(i=0; stutter[i]!=NULL; ++i) {
    puts(stutter[i]);
    free(stutter[i]);
  }
  free(stutter); /* free the array itself */

  return(0);
}
```